# Extend typedefinition of a classes object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am working with Restify (consider it as Express.js if you don't know Restify) and I would like to attach an object to the request object, so that I can access it in the following routes.

**A more concrete example:**

```
export const validate: ValidateFn = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: Next): Promise<void> => {    
  // Validate and parse token from headers
  const authHeader: string = req.header('authorization', null);
  const parsedToken: string = parseBearerToken(authHeader);
  if (parsedToken == null) { return next(new errors.InvalidCredentialsError('Missing authorization')); }

  // Verify token
  try {
    const data: {} = jwt.verify(parsedToken, config.apiServer.jwtSecret);
    req.user = data;
  } catch (err) {
    return next(new errors.NotAuthorizedError('Invalid authentication'));
  }

  return next();
};
```

In this line `req.user = data;` typescript is obviously yelling at me, because there is no field called `user` on the given Request object. I thought ideally I could simply extend the definition for the type `Request` in the restify namespace so that it would be still available under the same name but with an additional property `user: {};`.

Also I would be okay to create a new type (like `RequestValidated`), but I certainly want it to be available for the whole library namespace (no additional imports).

**So my question summarized in one sentence:**

How can I extend a third party library's definition to add my custom changes (like a custom property attached to the `Request` object), so that it is available for the same namespace without editing the original typing files (which are part of the definetely typed repo)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redeclare the module and the interface with-in the module and add the fields you need. The declarations will be merged into a single interface. You can put this in a separate file and include it in you project, and it will be picked up.

```
// restify.extra.d.ts
import { Request } from 'restify'
declare module 'restify' {
    interface Request {
        user: any
    }
}
// Other file:
import { Request } from 'restify'

let r: Request;
r.accepts("");
r.user = ";";
```

Comment: Wow I did expect that I had to extend the Request interface, but that wasn't necessary, the defined property just has been added. Perfect! Thanks a lot.